# I am trying to configure telegram bot with telegram bot library and I am getting an Error

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Error says
error: TelegramBot.h: No such file or directory
and 
ArduinoJson.h: No such file or directory.
What Should I do???

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not those libraries installed, so it is quite easy. Just grab libraries for [TelegramBot](https://github.com/CasaJasmina/TelegramBot-Library) and [ArduinoJSON](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/releases) and move them in the library directory (as a whole folder for each library).

For example, on Windows, it would be `C:/Users/Yourusername/Documents/Arduino/libraries`.

You can also install them with Arduino's [library manager](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries).

You can find more about how the libraries work in the official [docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries).